# C++ cling - any function like python's dir on the repl?

Tags: clang, cling

Is there a way to list an objects properties and methods like python's dir?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir

Answer (score 0):

.g would do something similar. Use .help for more information at the cling command prompt.